# How to use compose.materialIconsExtended in project(Compose for desktop)? -IntelliJ IDEA-

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose, icons, compose-desktop

I work with an app desktop and I use Compose for desktop.

I add this

```
    implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
```

to my project. But now I don't know how to access the icons.

[image: Icon()]

Can you show me how I use it.

Comment: `Icon(Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "contentDescription")`

Comment: thank you can I change its color and make it (Outlined, Rounded or Sharp)

Comment: `Icon(Icons.Outlined.Search, contentDescription = "contentDescription", tint = Color.Gray)`